# ShellScript 1: [: [: unexpected operator

Tags: linux, file, shell, text, compare

I am having a problem that I can't fix it. This might be some syntax problem, I already tryed so many solutions but didn't figure out the problem..

I tryed with brackets.. without brackets and I still get this error on the console:

```
1: [: [: unexpected operator
```

Can someone help me please ?
Here is my code:

```
if [ [ cmp --silent 1.fsa 1_.fsa ] returns any ]; then
  echo "Files are different!"
else
 echo "Files are identical!"
fi
```

By the way I am trying to compare two files inside a ShellScript, if they are the same I want to say:
"Files are identical!"
Otherwise I want to say: "Files are different!"

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: BashPitfalls #9 is relevant: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the brackets at all.

```
if cmp -s 1.fsa 1_.fsa; then
  echo "Files are identical!"
else
  echo "Files are different!"
fi
```

`[ ]` runs a command called `test`. If you read `man test`, you'll see that it doesn't understand "returns any" to mean anything at all; neither does it expect to see `[` passed to it.

So, the literal error you got:

```
[: [: unexpected operator
```

means that the `[` command (aka test) is complaining that it doesn't expect to be passed `[` as an argument.

Comment: Well thanks man, now I understood ;)
Thank you, really appreciated ;)
I am new to SH lol

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this solution:

```
if diff file1 file2 >/dev/null ; then
  echo Same
else
  echo Different
fi
```

But can someone said what was wrong with my implementation?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Using `cmp` is faster and more memory-efficient; using `diff` may work, but it isn't by any means the Right Thing.

Comment: Okay, I will your other implementation, thanks by the way for your feedback about perfomance ;)

Comment: To understand _why_ the performance is different, by the way -- `cmp -s` doesn't need to calculate _how_ things are different, so as soon as it sees any difference it can immediately exit. (If file sizes are different, it doesn't need to look in the contents for a mismatch at all, and can just immediately short-circuit there). Worst-case it reads both files, O(2n). `diff`, by contrast, needs to actually read both files and compute the shortest-distance path to transform one file to the other -- an algorithm with worst-case behavior somewhere in the neighborhood of O(n^3) if memory serves.